# Olympiad math problem - Show that a pair of lines is parallel

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation, homothety

> Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram. Draw a circunference that passes through $A$. It intersects $AB$,$AD,$ and $AC$ (for the second time), at points $E,F,$ and $G$, respectively. Lines $EG$ and $FG$ intersect $DC$ and $CB$ at $H$ and $I$, respectively.
>
> Show that $EF$ is parallel to $HI$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Perhaps drawing the labelled parallelogram and circle?

Comment: yes, I actually had this problem at my local ollimpiad, I drawed it but I got no further because of time trouble. At home I tried an aproach with similar triangles but got nowhere.

Comment: What do you mean by a circumference that passes through A?

Comment: Try and see if you can show that angles $\angle FEG = \angle IHG$. If they are equal then they are alternate interior angles between lines $EF$ and $HI$ which by definition then must be parallel.
Alternatively, show $\angle EFG = \angle HIG$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AEGF$ is cyclic, and hence $\angle GAF=\angle GEF$.

Next $\angle EGF=\angle HGI$, and hence $GHCI$ is also cyclic, and hence
$$
\angle GEF=\angle GAF=\angle BCA=\angle HIG
$$
and thus $FE\parallel HI$.

**Note.** The conclusion is still true even in the case in which $A$ is the centre of the circle. Indeed,
triangles $AGE$ and $CGH$ are similar, and hence both isosceles, and hence $CH=CG$. Also, triangles $AGF$ and $CGI$ are similar, and hence both isosceles, and hence $CI=CG$. Thus, 
$C$ is the centre of the circle which is defined by the point $H$, $G$ and $I$. Thus 
$$
2\angle FEH=\angle DAC = \angle GCI=2\angle EHI
$$
and hence $FE\parallel HI$.

Comment: Why is AEG isosceles? A is a point of the circunference, not the center.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the problem, assuming that $A$ is the centre of the circle. See my corrected answer.

Comment: Thx. The cyclic quatrilateral proofs allways kill me.

Comment: When you claim $\angle BCA=\angle HIG$ shouldn't it be $\angle BCA=\angle IHG$?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with a circle. $E,F,G$ can be arbitrary, they don't have to be on the same circle. with $A$.

[image]

Remember that a homothety takes line to a line parallel to it.

Observe a homothety $\mathcal{H}$ with center at $G$ that takes $F$ to $I$. Then it takes line $AD$ to a line $BC$ since they are parallel. Since it take line $AC$ to it self it follows that it takes $A$ to $C$ and thus line $AB$ to a line $CD$  since they are also parallel. Since it takes line $EH$ to it self we see that it takes $E$ to $H$. So it takes line $EF$ to a line $HI$ which means that $EF||HI$ and we are done.